# Camelia changii - fertilization problems

Tags: trees, fertilizer, camellia

My [*Camellia changii*](https://species.wikimedia.org/wiki/Camellia_changii) is losing its color and getting this aspects so sad. Is it lack of fertilizer or, conversely, excess? I live in Sintra, Portugal, and the climate is excellent for camellias in general.

Is there anyone who can help me?

[image: Camelia Changii with fertilization issues]

The soil is acidic, the fertilizer I am using is NPK 5-6-13 + 4% MgO a tablespoon every 30 days,  with good drainage and the watering is drop-by-drop.
This year the winter in Portugal  was very rainy and mild temperatures, only two or three days with minimum temperatures of 3ºC (37.4 ℉)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link underneath your post if you want to update it with extra information; don't post the update as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It might be an issue with the soil ph, see below. There is still little information in regard to this plant
[What are the growing conditions for Camelia azalea, especially its water needs?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/what-are-the-growing-conditions-for-camelia-azalea-especially-its-water-needs)

Comment: The soil is acidic, the fertilizer I am using is NPK 5-6-13 + 4% MgO a tablespoon every 30 days, with good drainage and the watering is drop-by-drop. This year the winter in Portugal was very rainy and mild temperatures, only two or three days with minimum temperatures of 3ºC (37.4 ℉)

Answer (score 1):

Changii camellias have lots of problems: the very first one depends on the sequence: preparation of the plant, delivery from China to elsewhere, repotting of the plant itself. The preparation, unless the delivery implies bare roots, consists on a reduction of the roots in the absence of a reduction of the leafy branches. The strong stress provoked and the time needed for a new rooting can kill the plants. Second point, grafts are made on every kind of japonica and often there is a retarded incompatibility with the camellia used. Changii does not like excess fertilization and watering but likes full sun, the last a condition not appreciated by japonicas. In conclusion, growing well Changii camellias is a true challenge.

Comment: hello Kiwoncello,You do not encourage me a lot. Any case, I have been lowering the the soil pH .  Itt was between 6 and 7, higher than I initially assumed.

I begin to notice a slight improvement over the coloring of the leaves and already has many new shoots. The flowering during this last summer, went very well.

Comment: New shoots are a good thing. I have several plants of both subtypes with red flowers and round leaf edges and pink flowers, pointed leaves: grafting them is an easy task (I'm using japonica seedlings) and of course grafted plants survive well in the absence of any delivery and repotting stress. Be optimistic....